# Unzip->Remove unwanted character->zip->Rename->move to different location Using SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS 2008 VERSION. I am looking for the below implementation using SSIS 2008 version.

1. Unzip file from the location say F:\ . When I unzip I will get one folder inside the folder I will get one .txt file.
2. Once I get the .txt file I have to read/any SSIS process to remove the first 2 letters of each row example below(text file will contains data like below):

   DA1234  345   test       test1   test2

   DA345   789   test4      test5   test7

Above is the content of text file. Each line starts with "DA" I need to remove that "DA" from each line.

1. Once "DA" is removed rename the .txt file and zip with same name as .txt file and send it to different location say D:.
2. Once sending process is success delete the file from the location Original location F:.

Please help me to achieve the above requirement.

Thanks...........

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of resources to help you out.  Most of these just need to be combined into a solution that fits your workflow.  Happy to help you further, but these should be some valuable resources.

- Downloadable task for unzipping/zipping files:  http://taskunzip.codeplex.com/
- Walk through on copying, renaming or deleting files:  [Rename files using File System task](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/KeithHyer/bidn-blog/2465/copy-and-rename-a-file-in-ssis-using-the-file-system-task)

You can also delete files using the File System Task.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply mainly I am looking for removing "DA"(in text file each line starts with "DA" as I mentioned above) from each line. Can you please provide me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

use Derived coulmn transforamation to replace DA with ""and insert into destination.For unzipping you can use script task or customised unzip task which can unzip automatically ,For renaming & moving files use File system task.